# python get new random name for every call of class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get new random name every time I call class.
I am defining it as

```
def namemethod():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(5))

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name=namemethod()):
        self.name = name
```

And I am calling `Test` class via for loop to get new name but I keep getting same name, isn't it suppose to call `init` method and get new random name?

```
for i in range(5):
    person = Test()
    print person.name
```

Why `person = Test()` not calling `namemethod` everytime?

Comment: What's `string.lowercase`??

Comment: @SilverSlash, probably https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lowercase

Comment: @davedwards Ah yes, it's slightly different in python 3.

Comment: Answers below are correct.  FYI, a more detailed explanation: "[Common Gotchas - Mutable Default Arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name=namemethod()):
        self.name = name
```

The default argument

```
name=namemethod()
```

only gets evaluated a single time for the entire class (default arguments always only get evaluated once)

What you probably want to do instead, is use `name=None` as default value for the `name` argument. The, in `__init__()`, you could do something like this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        if name is None:
            name = namemethod()

        self.name = name
```

Answer (score 3):

in your code, the `name=namemethod()` default argument is replaced permanently by a single instance returned by a call to `namemethod`

Your desired behaviour can be achieved using:

```
def namemethod():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(5))

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name if name is not None else namemethod()
```